# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class GoogleDriveProxeyActivity have you declared this

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to call one activity from another.

but I get this error:

`Unable to find explicit activity class GoogleDriveProxeyActivity have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`

when executing:

```
    private Uri saveFileToDrive() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GoogleDriveProxeyActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, SAVE_TO_DRIVE);

                //btw, how does this work if another action started?
                return null;
          }
```

(//btw, how does sending a return value after startActivityForResult works if another action started?)

what am I missing in the manifest?

```
    </activity>
            <activity
        android:name=".GoogleDriveProxeyActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**update**

my manifest package:

```
de.vogella.android.todos/AndroidManifest.xml
```

the problematic Activity:

```
package de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider;

public class GoogleDriveProxeyActivity extends Activity {
```

Comment: Have you tried to use full package name before class name in manifest? Something like <activity android:name="com.project.GoogleDriveProxeyActivity" > ?

Comment: If the `Activity` is from library project with different package from your app, use full package name. The dot in `android:name=".Activity"` is just a shorthand of your app's package name.

Comment: @antimo but the activity is in my app package. not a different one. So dot should have worked.

Comment: If `GoogleDriveProxeyActivity` is inside another package **in** your app, then you need to append the additional package. However, since currently it's not clear, I couldn't diagnose the issue. Could you edit your post to show the package in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, and also the package name inside `GoogleDriveProxeyActivity.java`?

Comment: thanks. I have added. Strangely adding the full package helped.

Comment: That's the issue: When you use `.GoogleDriveProxeyActivity`, it means `de.vogella.android.todos.GoogleDriveProxeyActivity`, not `de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider.GoogleDriveProxeyActivity`. You can use the "." shorthand like this `.contentprovider.GoogleDriveProxeyActivity` :)

Comment: can you post an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use the full name of your activity including the namespace:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sample.GoogleDriveProxeyActivity" >
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: btw, are the view and defualt intent nescesarry ?

Comment: Well, it depends on what the activity is supposed to do. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: but the activity is in my app package. not a different one. So dot should have worked.

Comment: worked for me. was trying to launch a LoginActivity.

Comment: Thanks szymon.. my activity was in different package ..it worked

Answer (score 1):

Add `[Activity]` on top of your class e. g.;

```
[Activity]
class MyActivityClass : Activity
{
}
```

Comment: this worked for me.  Didn't need to add the action to the manifest at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Rebuild project". Manifest file changes are sometimes not detected unless the project is rebuilt.